# How to suppress "function is never used" warning for a function used by tests?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a program in Rust and I have some tests for it. I wrote a helper function for these tests, but whenever I build using `cargo build` it warns me that the function is never used:

> warning: function is never used: ... #[warn(dead_code)] on by default

How I can mark this function as used so as not to get the warnings?

Comment: Adding a `pub` before `mod utils` fixed the problem for me as pointed out in [this comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/46379#issuecomment-548787629)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

#### Specific question

> How I can mark this function as used so as not to get the warnings?

The Rust compiler runs many [lints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) to warn you about possible issues in your code and the `dead_code` lint is one of them. It can be very useful in pointing out mistakes when code is complete, but may also be a nuisance at earlier stages. Often, this can be solved by either deleting unused code, or by marking a public method. However, all lints can be turned off by `allow`ing them, and your error message (`#[warn(dead_code)] on by default`) contains the name of the lint you could disable.

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
fn my_unused_function() {}
```

#### Alternative for testing

> I wrote a helper function for these tests, but whenever I build using `cargo build` it warns me that the function is never used.

This happens to be a special case, which is that code that is only used for testing isn't needed in the real executable and should probably not be included.

In order to optionally disable compilation of test code, you can mark it accordingly using the [`cfg` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/conditional-compilation.html) with the `test` profile.

```
#[cfg(test)]
fn my_test_specific_function() {}
```

When marked in this way, the compiler knows to ignore the method during compilation. This is similar to commonly used `ifdef` usage in other languages like C or C++, where you are telling a preprocessor to ignore the enclosed code unless `TESTING` is defined.

```c
#ifdef TESTING
...
#endif
```

Comment: Am I missing something?  I'm doing [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) and don't want to see warnings for tests that *are* being used by tests **when I'm  testing**.  If I were to produce a release build without the tests and with no implemented callers, *then* I would expect to see warnings, as the functions are truly not being used.  Is there a way to have Rust warn me when the functions are **actually** not being used?

Comment: That's where the second case comes in, #[cfg(test)] would not turn off any dead code checks, so you would still have all warnings as expected, but the tests methods would only be included in a test version.

Comment: Can this be configured project-wide in some Cargo configuration file?

Comment: Worth noting that `cargo check --tests` runs checks in the test configuration, and thus will not flag items as dead if they are used in tests.

Comment: It's `#![allow(dead_code)]`, right? Your example is missing the `!`

Comment: @MichaelMrozek `#![...]` applies the attribute to the encompassing scope whereas `#[...]` is just applied to the following item. As shown, this suppresses the warning *only* for that function. [See Attributes in the Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html)

Answer (score 43):

For people getting this warning while making a rust library, you may get this if you don't have your modules set to pub in your lib.rs.

```
pub mod foo;
```

Comment: I found this useful when having a shared module in the `/tests` folder. Each test file is compiled separately to a test runner binary and so any functions not used by that particular test file are marked as 'never used' even if other test files use them. Marking 'mod' statements for the common module as 'pub' means those warnings go away.

Comment: Nailed it.  I always forget this piece of the puzzle when creating library functions.

Answer (score 20):

If something is only used in tests, it should be omitted altogether. This can be done with the `#[cfg(test)]` attribute.

Comment: "If something is only used in tests, it should be omitted altogether."

What if you're writing a library, where the intent is for others' code, not this one, to use it?

Comment: @SilasBarta: then it will be a public function, and not dead code.

Comment: Because the other responses aren't saying this very explicitly, and I keep having to rediscover this myself: if you're getting a dead code warning on a library function that you have tests for, one common reason for it is that you forgot to mark it `pub`.

Comment: @rspeer Also, the method you are getting the warning for might be public but the struct that method belongs to might not be.

Answer (score 13):

There is another situation where this can occur. If you have several helper functions in a module, e.g. in `tests/utils/mod.rs` and then several integration tests (`tests/a.rs`, `tests/b.rs`) each of which does

```rust
mod utils;
use utils::...;
```

then you will get dead code warnings if you do not use all of the code from all of the tests. For example if test `a.rs` only uses `utils::foo` and `b.rs` only uses `utils::bar` then you will get dead code warnings for both.

That is because each test is compiled as an independent crate. [Here is the bug report for it.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/46379) It looks difficult to solve so I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: The only answer that faces the real problem. Adding a `pub` before `mod utils` fixed the problem for me, as pointed out in [this comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/46379#issuecomment-548787629). Thanks for the reference

Answer (score 7):

`dead_code` is a lint, which means you can `allow` it on the thing that's causing it to trigger.

```rust
#[allow(dead_code)]
fn dummy() {}

fn main() {}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can disable specific lints for a whole project in Rust by going into your `main.rs` file and adding the following at the very top of the file:

```
#![allow(
dead_code,
unused_imports
)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You max prefix the unused function name with an underscore:

```
fn _dummy() {}

fn main() {}
```

See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/listing/warn-by-default.html#dead-code

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I found that setting the main function to `public`:

`pub fn main()`

and then copying my main.rs file to lib.rs

`cp src/main.rs src/lib.rs`

then recompiling fixed this.

No need to use a macro for it, although the macro should work for non main functions.