# Rust book unit test example results in dead code warning - why?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, dead-code

While learning Rust and trying out the example unit test related code from the Rust book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-01-writing-tests.html

I get a warning regarding dead code that clearly is being exercised by the unit test.  Why is that?

Code in lib.rs

```
struct Rectangle {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}

impl Rectangle {
    fn can_hold(&self, other: &Rectangle) -> bool {
        self.width > other.width && self.height > other.height
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    
    #[test]
    fn larger_can_hold_smaller() {
        let larger = Rectangle {
            width: 8,
            height: 7,
        };
        let smaller = Rectangle {
            width: 5,
            height: 1,
        };

        assert!(larger.can_hold(&smaller));
    }
}
```

Result when running cargo test

```
$ cargo test
   Compiling adder v0.1.0 (/Users/khorkrak/projects/rust/adder)
warning: associated function is never used: `can_hold`
 --> src/lib.rs:8:8
  |
8 |     fn can_hold(&self, other: &Rectangle) -> bool {
  |        ^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default

warning: 1 warning emitted

    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.19s
     Running target/debug/deps/adder-1082c4b063a8fbe6

running 1 test
test tests::larger_can_hold_smaller ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

   Doc-tests adder

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

$ rustc --version
rustc 1.50.0 (cb75ad5db 2021-02-10)
```

Comment: I noticed that if I run the tests specifying --lib that this does not occur. I'm still unclear though why it's working like this though sans the --lib.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress "function is never used" warning for a function used by tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900809/how-to-suppress-function-is-never-used-warning-for-a-function-used-by-tests) *"...code that is only used for testing isn't needed in the real executable and should probably not be included."*

Comment: Not quite - as this code isn't just code used for testing. However, the answer was in a comment in there toward the end: 
"Because the other responses aren't saying this very explicitly, and I keep having to rediscover this myself: if you're getting a dead code warning on a library function that you have tests for, one common reason for it is that you forgot to mark it pub. – rspeer Jul 18 '19 at 21:49"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing this

```
struct Rectangle {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}

impl Rectangle {
    fn can_hold(&self, other: &Rectangle) -> bool {
        self.width > other.width && self.height > other.height
    }
}
```

to this makes the dead code warning go away.

```
pub struct Rectangle {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}

impl Rectangle {
    pub fn can_hold(&self, other: &Rectangle) -> bool {
        self.width > other.width && self.height > other.height
    }
}
```

Both the structure and method tested need to be public.

Comment: Sadly, after doing this warning never shows up again even if the function is not used