# Rust: organizing tests so that modules of test-only functions/constants don't cause "x is never used" warnings

Tags: testing, rust

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900809/how-to-suppress-function-is-never-used-warning-for-a-function-used-by-tests/32908553) but with a twist. I have, in my lib.rs, a test suite that begins:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use crate::test_data::{CONSTANT1, CONSTANT2};
⋮
};
```

`test_data` contains long arrays of accepted values for use in testing.

At the start of `lib.rs`, I include:

```rust
mod test_data;
```

but Rust gives warnings that, in my tests that use `CONSTANT1` etc. that those constants are never used.

This *is* solved, as in the linked SO question above, by changing this to `pub mod test_data;`, but my understanding is that then end users of my library will see these constants of test data exposed to them, which is not the intent.

Is there a better way to organize my test so that I can have private modules that are test-only data/functions, that will not trigger "x is never used" errors?

Comment: The `#[cfg(test)]` attribute can be used elsewhere to only enable items during tests. You can add it onto your private modules' declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those constants are only intended for use in tests, you can annotate them as such and keep them private:

```
#[cfg(test)]
const CONSTANT1: u64 = 1;
```

Or entire test modules:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test_stuff {
    pub(crate) const CONSTANT1: u64 = 1;

    pub(crate) fn test_utility() {
    }
}
```