# Why is rust complaining about an unused function when it is only used from tests?

Tags: rust, warnings, dead-code

When a function is only called from tests rust complains that it is never used. Why does this happen and how to fix this?

Example:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=52d8368dc5f30cf6e16184fcbdc372dc

```rust
fn greet() {
    println!("Hello!")
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_greet() {
        greet();
    }
}
```

I get the following compiler warning:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
warning: function is never used: `greet`
 --> src/lib.rs:1:4
  |
1 | fn greet() {
  |    ^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default

warning: 1 warning emitted
```

Comment: Relevant: [How to suppress “function is never used” warning for a function used by tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32900809/2189130)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress "function is never used" warning for a function used by tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900809/how-to-suppress-function-is-never-used-warning-for-a-function-used-by-tests)

Comment: @Jmb In my case the correct solution was to mark the function as pub. See my answer

Comment: Same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67897487/5397009) in the duplicate, then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In rust fn is private by default. greet() is not accessible outside your module. If greet() is not used inside it except in tests, then rust is correctly flagging it as dead code.

If greet() is supposed to be part of your public interface mark it as pub:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8a8c50b97fe3f1eb72a01a6252e9bfe6

```rust
pub fn greet() {
    println!("Hello!")
}
```

If greet() is a helper intended to be only used in tests move it inside mod tests:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3dc51a36b4d5403ca655dec0210e4098

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    fn greet() {
        println!("Hello!")
    }
    
    #[test]
    fn test_greet() {
        greet();
    }
}
```